# UISearchBar background while searching

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

How do you change the background when using the `UISearchBar`.
When I start the search the background behind by `UITableView` changes to white.
 How do I change that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have one great example of UITableview with Search bar and its operation.

I think this blog should help you..

http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/uitableview-%E2%80%93-4-searching-table-view/

in this example they used tableview with search bar and with layer view when you touch on searchbar
enjoy it...

Comment: This is not what I am looking for but thanks for the Blog anyways.

Comment: I found the solution here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617224/how-to-add-a-custom-background-to-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-table-view